# I want to delete just one specific value or line from Text File

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

1. this code to print all courses from text file for student and if he want to unregister from some course and the course which he will select it it will be deleted from the file , i saw many Questions like that but i can't use this way cuz i don't want to sotre the data in another file except one line (which will be deleted) and rename it cuz the data has a refrence for every student , **Thanks in Advance** ...

   ```
       ifstream CourseAssign("C:\\StudentsCourses.txt") ;
             int z=0 , y =1 ;

                if(!CourseAssign.is_open()) {
                     cout << "Error opening" ;
                        }

           while( CourseAssign >> Student_Details[*n].CourseName_of_Student[z]){
               cout << y << Student_Details[*n].CourseName_of_Student[z] ;
                   z++;
                   y++;
               }

         int Num2 ;
   ```
2. here the user(Student) should enter a number and the course will be deleted 
   but i just need the suitable code to do it ,**again i can't use ordinary ways**

   ```
         cout << "Which Course do you wanna unregister it" ;
              cin >> Num2 ;
              z = Num2; 
              z -= 1 ;
   ```

> my file is just like that

```
           1:CS

           2:Ai 

           3:Data Structure
```

Answer (score 1):

At minimum you will have to read the file until the data you want to delete, then read everything that follows. Unless you use a binary file format with a special layout it is generally easier to simply re-write the entire file than to try and change a file in-place.

Comment: yes sure , i know that i should read the full file until the data that i want to delete it , i have searched a lot to find a new ways like built-in function but i didn't find Asnwer ,  so is there any way to delete just one value from text file without storing other variables in another file except the var which i want to delete it and delete the file then rename the new file